# change background color or text color before clicking in listview, dynamically using json

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to change the background color or text color of each row displayed based on the data dynamically.I have modified the example/SourceCode which I got online,will paste the code below.

Change Backgroundcolor of row to Blue if magnitude > 8.5

```
              or
```

Change Backgroundcolor of Text to Blue if magnitude > 8.5

Note:Color should change, Before Clicking on the list.

Thanks a lot I appreciate the help.

Main.Java

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


     String jString="{\"earthquakes\": [{ \"eqid\": \"c0001xgp\", \"magnitude\": 8.8, \"lng\": 142.369, \"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2011-03-11 04:46:23\", \"depth\": 24.4,\"lat\": 38.322 },{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.4,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172},{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.5,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172},{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.6,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172},{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.7,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172}]}";
    //   JSONObject  json=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(jString);
     JSONObject jObject = null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 


        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = jObject.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
                map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
                mylist.add(map);    


            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

JSONfunctions.java

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

      //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

listplaceholder.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `setViewBinder()` method of your Adapter. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder%29).

Try the following code and let me know:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            int v=view.getId();
            if(v==R.id.item_subtitle && Float.valueOf(data.toString())>8.5){
                ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            TextView TV=(TextView) view;
            TV.setText(data.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply midoalageb,Can you please write in the code to make it work.Please,I would appreciate your help greatly.

Comment: hi android ppl,Can anyone please write the code ...I would appreciate your help greatly.Urgent requirement.

Comment: Thanks You Sir,That was a great help.God Bless you.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleAdapter is for static data. If you want to optimize it you'd better off create your own custom adapter.

Comment: Thanks April I tried to do the same but I was unable to get the json response within the list other than this project.Can you please give me a demo code to fill the same data as above in the list along with changing the text/background color .Have been trying for long time unable to get any insight regarding json data populate in list.Any sort of help would be great.

Comment: here is sample of `CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<T>`
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: Thanks April for the link,will try that too.